# Why does the Google Cloud Build configuration file not use an entrypoint for docker build step(s)?

Tags: google-cloud-build

In general I see cloud build config examples like the one below. Why does the cloud-sdk build step use an entrypoint when the docker build steps do not?

```
steps:
# Build the container image
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '--tag', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name','.']
# Push the container image to Container Registry
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name']
# Deploy container image to Cloud Run
- name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
  entrypoint: 'gcloud'
  args: ['run', 'deploy', 'project-name', '--image', 'gcr.io/project-id/project-name', '--region', 'us-central1']
```

My running theory is that it has to do with the last word of the `name` being the same as the `cmd` keyword arg. eg. `gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker` ends in `docker` but the `cloud-sdk` requires the `cmd` keyword `gcloud` to run.

Comment: Why don't you use the cloud builder instead?

Comment: Example might be out of date it uses cloudsdktool see [Deploying to Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#building_and_deploying_a_container) good tip though I will use cloud-builders/gcloud without the entrypoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does the cloud-sdk build step use an entrypoint when the docker build steps do not?

This is because entrypoint `gcloud` will be used to invoke the `gcloud run deploy` command to deploy it in Cloud Run.

On the other hand, Dockerfile has its own configuration for being open source so that it would work on other platforms aside from gcloud.

Additional information regarding `args` and `entrypoint` is available in this link on [Structure of a build config file](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#args).